# Decompose string of different symbols in python

Tags: python, regex, string

is it possible to efficiently decompose a string like this:

```
'G:1{l:3:"cat";v:30;l:3:"dog";v:0;l:5:"horse";v:20;l:6:"rabbit";v:50;}'
```

into this for further processing:

```
"cat", 30
"dog", 0
"horse", 20
"rabbit", 50
```

I tried to use Regex patterns and complicated loops but I did not get far.

Comment: what you have tried show us

Comment: It follows a pattern, so it would be pretty easy to parse with regex.

Comment: I used the pattern '(["])\w+' to extract the names but I do not understand how to extract 2 patterns at the same time

Comment: @presa it's ok just wanted to see what you have tried. just check the answers below. i have also added one along with explanation.

Comment: Do you need to keep the double quotes `""` ?

Comment: @PedroLobito i guess yes. regex he commented seems to capture `"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this mate**

```
\"[A-Za-z]+\"|(?<=v:)\d+
```

> Explanation

- `\"[A-Za-z]+\"` - Matches `"` followed by any number of `alphabet` follwed by `"`.
- `|` - Alternation works same as logical OR.
- `(?<=v:)\d+` - Matches any `v:` followed by any number.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q2wXf7/1/)

Comment: @presa always happy to help :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regex to find the pattern:

```
import re

s = 'G:1{l:3:"cat";v:30;l:3:"dog";v:0;l:5:"horse";v:20;l:6:"rabbit";v:50;}'

re.findall(r'("[A-Za-z]+");v:(\d+)', s)
# [('"cat"', '30'), ('"dog"', '0'), ('"horse"', '20'), ('"rabbit"', '50')]
```

With this list you should be able to get it in the format you want:

```
for row in re.findall(r'("[A-Za-z]+");v:(\d+)', s):
    print("{}, {}".format(*row))
# "cat", 30
# "dog", 0
# "horse", 20
# "rabbit", 50
```

Comment: I don't think the `"` are part of the result. You could use non-capturing groups

Comment: Why are you escaping all those different characters?  It's unnecessary.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: True, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following pattern, and then split it:

```
import re

your_string = 'G:1{l:3:"cat";v:30;l:3:"dog";v:0;l:5:"horse";v:20;l:6:"rabbit";v:50;}'

result = [val.split('";v:') for val in re.findall('l:\d:"(\w+\";v:\d+);', your_string)]
```

**Output**

```
[['cat', '30'], ['dog', '0'], ['horse', '20'], ['rabbit', '50']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
import re
x = 'G:1{l:3:"cat";v:30;l:3:"dog";v:0;l:5:"horse";v:20;l:6:"rabbit";v:50;}'
r = re.findall(r'(".*?");v:(\d+)', x)
for y in r:
    print(f"{y[0]}, {y[1]}")
```

---

**Output:**

```
"cat", 30
"dog", 0
"horse", 20
"rabbit", 50
```

---

[Python Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/QM5)